# Carousel Caption Lowest Position

Tags: html, css, carousel

Is there a way I can reposition the bootstrap carousel caption to the lowest part of the image? CSS follows:

```
.carousel-caption {
    max-width: 100%;
    width:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: check [w3School](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)

Comment: Have you tried `bottom: 0;`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bottom:0px`

```
.carousel-caption {
  max-width: 100%;
  width:100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```